# puppet: how to submit command "yum update" to all agents?

Tags: puppet, yum, puppetmaster

I'm new to puppet and trying to create manifest which will request all agents to update all currently installed yum packages.

What should be the best way to describe this in manifest?

Comment: So every time Puppet runs (normally every 30 minutes), you want to update all installed packages?

Comment: I find a best way, but I don't have enterprise.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Well, it's [super-easy with Puppet Enterprise and MCollective](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4XuKm.png)...

But in your case, you're probably going to have to [produce a manifest](http://geekdom.wesmo.com/2014/01/06/using-puppet-to-perform-yum-update/) that runs an `exec` of `/usr/bin/yum -y -q update`.

You can also just create a puppet cron resource to do this on a more sane schedule...

Comment: are you sure about MCollective? I think the `package` agent only allows `update` on a single package, not all.

Comment: The Marionette Collective `package` agent can't do that yet, but there are agents for `mco` out there that could do this, see [shellout](https://github.com/slaney/mcollective-plugins/blob/master/agent/shellout.rb) for an example.

Comment: You can run arbitrary command via `mco` with the right plugins.